# VBA load webpage and pull data in memory

Tags: javascript, windows, vba, browser

If I am just seeing if this is possible. So for any website, if I want to pull the source code from a different page of a website (have it load, etc) without actually going to the webpage is this possible? Can this be done in memory for example? In example, if I have a website like cnn.com and instead of actually clicking on an article link and going to that page, if I just want to pull the information from that page, but remain on the main page, is this possible? If it is possible, how would I go about doing it? thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by pulling source code w/o going without going to a webpage. Similarly what do you mean by doing this "in-memory"? Every application runs in RAM, in-memory computing differs only that you keep e.g. a whole database in memory w/o loading bits of tables/columns to memory every now and then. Please provide some clarification.

**Simulate browsing**

You can use the "InternetExplorer.Application" object to load a webpage and "remain on the page": (http://www.analystcave.com/web-scraping-tutorial/#Excel_IE_Object).

This will open Google in the background.

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False 
IE.Navigate "http://www.google.com/"
Do While IE.Busy 'We need to wait until the page has loaded
  Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
```

**Load HTML page (no browser)**

This will show the HTML of a Web Page w/o a browser as a proxy:

```
Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
XMLHTTP.Open "GET", "http://www.google.com", False
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
XMLHTTP.send
MsgBox XMLHTTP.ResponseText
```

(http://www.analystcave.com/web-scraping-tutorial/#XMLHttpRequest_object)

Comment: I was not as clear as I should have been. I mean in regards to an internal link. Something like javascript:gotopage('DATA'). This page has a link that one can click on and it will take them there, but I would just like to pull the data from the page without going there. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Show the source code of "javascript:gotopage('DATA')". What ever it does I still don't understand how you distinct that it does not "go there". It must somehow "go there" or else it can't pull the data from the link regardless if you use AJAX or a HTTP request.